# Best way to tag/identify processes for killing them later?

Tags: linux, startup-scripts

In my linux startup scripts, when I start a process like (openvpn used for this example, but the question is general to any process);

```
openvpn --config /etc/myserver.conf
```

what is the best way to find it and be 100% certain it's the right process and kill it in the stop section? I normally use stuff like:

```
pid=$(ps -efww | grep -v grep | grep openvpn | grep /etc/myserver.conf | awk '{print $2}')
```

Sure it works nearly all of the time, but sometimes there are issues with accidentally matching processes with nearly the same name (e.g. myserver.conf-new), so I'm looking for a better approach.

- Some processes have a way to store the pid somewhere, that's fine, but generally I'm skeptical of killing processes solely based on a pid sitting in a file somewhere.
- Solaris has [projects](http://www.princeton.edu/~unix/Solaris/troubleshoot/resmgmt.html), it's not all roses in my limited experience because you have to set up /etc/projects first, but it does make it easy to tag and later find processes.
- Maybe using the environment, like setting an environment variable like (MYID=myserver) and then looking for it with `ps e -ef | grep MYID=myserver`? Still may suffer the same problem with accidental matching.

I wish there were something easy like:

```
launch --tag myserver openvpn --config /etc/myserver.conf
```

and

```
pgrep --tag myserver
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you @Iain, @KyleSmith, and @M_1 for your answers, and for helping me get started on Server Fault. If I had more rep here I'd +1 you guys. (Edit: now I have rep, +1s all around).

I'm going to answer my own question because I've found something that does what I was looking for: a general solution that avoids imprecise pattern matching with ps, and doesn't use pid files. It's completely subjective that this would be the "best" way because there's obviously a long and successful history in unix of using pid files, however this was something I explicitly said I didn't like for various reasons, and those are: they can be tricky to create properly, different for every piece of software, done differently on every distro, can be stale/overwritten, and inherently don't necessarily represent what's actually going on. I'd rather use some kind of process tagging, ask the kernel and get real answers.

Trimmed down example:

```
#!/bin/sh
_TAG=d726cc7fa57a308afdc057b228a13f6d
case "$1" in
start)
  _TAG=$_TAG ./self-backgrounding-process
  _TAG=$_TAG ./non-self-backgrounding-process &
  ;;
stop)
  pids=$(grep -l "\b_TAG=$_TAG\b" /proc/*/environ | cut -d/ -f3)
  [ -n "$pids" ] && kill $pids
  ;;
esac
```

The key points are:

- using an md5sum (something very unlikely to be accidentally matched) for the tag
- using a different tag in each service's startup script
- querying /proc/*/environ to get an accurate list of running/relevant/tagged processes
- using [grep with \b](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to match word boundaries to ensure an exact match

I'm not sure I like polluting the environment, but I don't know of any other way (e.g. Solaris projects) to tag a linux process in an arbitrary way that I can ask the kernel for later. At least, /proc/<pid>/environ appears to [reflect the environment at startup, and not be affected by any changes the process might make after](https://serverfault.com/questions/66363/environment-variables-of-a-running-process-on-unix/79463#79463), which suggests this should be reliable, however, there's the chance this could change unexpectedly. This may or may not work outside Linux, depending on the OS's /proc and grep implementation.

I think I'll give it a try for a while and see how it goes.

Comment: One thing that occurred to me later is this technique doesn't find processes started by hand. Not a big deal maybe, but not good either.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be afraid of pidfiles, of they're tried and true and typically owned by root!  :)

Most distributions use a standard function or binary to launch daemons and store the resultant PID in a file.  In Debian, for example, you have start-stop-daemon with the `--pidfile` option.  Other distributions have `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` (or similiar) that are used for starting daemons.  Check some of the more generic startup scripts included with your distribution.

Comment: You're probably right on the point don't be afraid of pidfiles. I'll check out my system startup script libs for some more ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A nice idea would be to use a simple bash wrapper script that writes a lock/pid file of that application (commonly used in webservers or databases) and then use that file to kill exactly this one process if needed.

Comment: I like this idea, but sometimes the programs I call fork themselves into the background, so it's tough to keep track of the right pid.

Answer (score 2):

For openvpn in particular you can use the `--writepid /path/to/file` command line option e.g.

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --writepid /var/run/openvpn/server.pid  --config /etc/myserver.conf ...
```

Which will write the PID of the openvpn main process to the named file.

In general you can wrap your program in a small script and use the bash `$!` builtin variable to write the pid to a file

```
#!/bin/bash
yourcommand &
echo $! >/path/to/pid.file
```

Comment: Good point on --writepid for openvppn, I may use that for openvpn in particular. I'll have to find another program to use as an example, but openvpn forks into the background, so if I launch it with & ($! only appears to work when you background something), then you end up with the wrong pid.

Comment: @SteveKehlet: Having something write a PID file is generally the way to do this. Most daemons will write a PID file so you don't need to wrap them you just need to know (or tell) where the PID file is. You only need to write a wrapper for something that doesn't and can't be made to create it's own PID file. Beyond that everything becomes a special case.

Comment: Good point. I may think I have an unusually high number of special cases, but I shouldn't forget that some of them are actually not. Thank you for your answers Iain.