# List environment variables of a running process on AIX without character limit

Tags: unix, process, aix, environment-variables, ps

Today I was trying to debug an issue where a process was not picking up the correct environmental variable. It took us hours before we realized that it wasn't picking up the correct variable.

I tried to list them using the solution here: https://serverfault.com/a/104175/90224 (`ps eww [pid]`), but it seems to have a character limit of something like 3155 characters, which is not even close to enough for the particular application. (It's not even done printing the command line options at that point)

Is there another method I can use on AIX to find it?
I am a software developer, so I wouldn't mind a solution requiring a bit of code either.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with one more `w` you *should* get it all according to the man page:

> ```
> ewww
> ```
>
> Wraps display from the e flag and displays the `ENV` list until it reaches the `INT_MAX` value.

That's a pretty big limit.

If you're looking at creating yourself tools for this, you should look into the [`getevars`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/getevars.htm) and [`geteargs`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/getevars.htm) functions which `ps` uses for the `ewww` display.

Here's a naïve usage of `getevars`, prints its own environment (limit ~1Mb):

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <procinfo.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ENV_MAX (1024*1024)

int main(void)
{
    struct procentry64 pe;
    char buffer[ENV_MAX];
    pe.pi_pid = getpid();
    int rc = getevars(&pe, sizeof(pe), buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (rc != 0) {
        perror("getevars");
        return 1;
    }
    buffer[ENV_MAX-2] = buffer[ENV_MAX-1] = 0;
    char *cur = buffer;
    char *end = buffer+sizeof(buffer);
    while ((*cur) && (cur < end)) {
        int len = puts(cur);
        cur += len;
    }
    return 0;
}
```